# Changes need to make in web application to use hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

In my project , web application runs on different servers. On each server , application cache data during startup in ehcache and maps. I want to migrate to hazelcast. What are the changes need to make to use Hazelcast?

Answer (score 0):

Three steps will get you started:

1. You need Hazelcast on the classpath.

For example, include http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/hazelcast/hazelcast/3.7.4/hazelcast-3.7.4.jar in your webapp's `lib` folder.

2. Create a Hazelcast instance in that webapp

For example, `HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();`

3. Obtain a map reference, to use as if it was a local map

For example, `java.util.Map<?, ?> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("name");`

Step 2 is where you'll likely have the most difficulty. You want the Hazelcast instances to find each other. They will do this using multicast by default, but if this is blocked for you you will need to be more explicit with the config and specify host addresses.
 Send me a DM if you need help.

Comment: Can you please provide detail on the step2 ? How does Hazelcast instances find each other on different servers ?

Comment: Multicast discovery is explained here : http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-members-by-multicast . Basically each webapp will broadcast out and form a cluster with any webapps that responds. It's the easiest way, but from there you can amend the configuration if you want more control over which processes join together.